# Calculating number of rows in a file created by UTL_FILE

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a PLSQL package, that writes out an extract from an Oracle table into multiple files. Each file can have maximum of 50000000 rows. Generally, 5 or 6 such files are created. I am using UTL_FILE functionality to create these extract files.

I have a requirement to log generated file names and number of rows in the generated file to an Oracle table.

I can log the file names, but how I can log the number of rows exported to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How? Count them one-by-one.

- create a local variable
- increment it after each `UTL_FILE.put_line` call
- log it after you're done

I've just tested it, output (result of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`) looks like e.g.

```
ocit_4001_1.txt: 37465 row(s)
ocit_4001_2.txt: 37464 row(s)
ocit_4001_3.txt: 37462 row(s)
```